# Improve your answer with other users' answers?

Tags: discussion, quality-improvement

For a specific problem there can be multiple solutions, yet some are very similar but they have their own differences/peculiarities/advantages/disadvantages and for the sake of the argument should be placed together. Obviously I'm talking about very small changes or similar methods.

In this case should I include other users' answers in my answer?

If so, should I reference the user(s) that made them?

Comment: With regard to the last part: Attribution is required. That is in the license model SE uses.

Comment: "should be placed together" You need to support that assertion.  Why is it important for different answers to be placed in one answer, instead of having different answers in different answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a problem has multiple solutions, then those solutions should generally be in their own separate answers.

If you want to compare a given solution with other solutions, you're free to include that comparison in your answer.  If you need to quote or reference a snippet of someone else's answer to do so, make sure you cite it appropriately.

If you want to build off of the work of another answer to improve it and come up with an additional solution, you're free to do that as well, just make sure to again cite what work is not your own.

If you have your own solution and someone else has provided another solution, whether similar or not, then there is no reason to include their work in yours (or vice versa) for its own sake.  If a problem just has several answers, then it has several answers.